# Get Javascript object stored in file, into php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a `Switches.js` javascript file, like this:

```
//GLOBAL switches
//Change the values accordingly

var SWITCHES = {
    uber:        true, //Uber
    social:      true, //Social media pulgins
    g_charts:    true, //Google Charts
    g_captcha:   true, //Google Captcha
    g_analytics: true, //Google Analytics
    data_base:   true, //Inserts user input data into DataBase
    print:       true, //Print option
    pdf:         true, //Download PDF report option
    https:       true  //true for https, false for http
};
```

This JS file is stored in my server.

Is there a way to get that object and one of those properties into a php variable? I think that should be around the php functions `file_get_contents` and `json_decode`, but how do I take into account the comments in the JS file and that variable `SWITCHES` in particular?

```
$file_content = file_get_contents("Switches.js");
//some stuff
$http_switch = $SWITCHES[https];
```

AJAX nor jQuery are an option because this is to be run purely server side.

Comment: It's JavaScript, not JSON, so you can't use `json_decode()`. How about converting the `Switches.js` to `Switches.json` instead?

Comment: @Svenskunganka , thank you for the reply. And then how could I use such JS `SWICTHES` variable in my global JS scope?

Comment: You'd use the equivalent JavaScript function `JSON.decode()` to turn it into a JavaScript Object.

Comment: seems interesting your suggestion and it solves my problem. Could you reply accordingly with detailed explanation being then tagged as solved? `:)`

Comment: There we go, btw I wrote a typo in one of my previous comments, `JSON.decode()` is meant to be `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Switches.js` is JavaScript and not JSON, you can't use `json_decode()`. Instead you should convert it to JSON and decode/parse it both client-side and server-side:

In PHP, you'd do:

```
$data = file_get_contents("Switches.json");
$switches = json_decode($data);
```

And then client-side you fetch it via AJAX and parse:

```
$.get("/Switches.json", function (data) {
  var switches = JSON.parse(data)
})
```

Your `Switches.json` file would then be (JSON files must not have comments):

```
{
    "uber": true,
    "social": true,
    "g_charts": true,
    "g_captcha": true,
    "g_analytics": true,
    "data_base": true,
    "print": true,
    "pdf": true,
    "https": true
}
```

Comment: is it possible to fetch it synchronously without AJAX? I'll need those variables right away for all the other JS files.

Comment: Yeah with `var switches = JSON.parse($.get("/Switches.json"))`. However synchronous requests are deprecated so it is adviced not to use that. From MDN docs: *Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.*

Comment: all my JS files are loaded at the end right before the `</body>`, so there is no issue with user experience.